IBKR TWS API Java - Canceling reqMktData snapshot results in error 300 - can't find Eid with tickerId
I am trying to gather a snapshot of a full option chain in IBKR TWS API in Java. My goal is to cancel the reqMktData call after I receive the bid, ask, and delta of each contract. All other tick data that comes in is useless for my purposes, so I'd like to free up resources. However, I am getting the following error sporadically (not every time):

IB Error: 140 300 Can't find EId with tickerId:140

My workflow is pretty simple -

reqContractDetails to get option chain info
for each contract, reqkMktData()
when the bid and ask from tickPrice and the delta from tickOptionComputation are populated in an object:
call cancelMktData

It seems I am somehow creating a race condition between tickSnapshotEnd and cancelMktData, which happens in 1 out of 10 contract I am going through. It doesn't seem to actually affect the computations I'm doing but is enough to fill my console with errors.
Here is some code snippets of my work so far. First I get the entire options chain of a given ticker:
public void getChain() {
        Contract contract = new Contract();
        contract.symbol("MSFT");
        contract.exchange("SMART");
        contract.secType("OPT");
        contract.currency("USD");
        contract.right("P");
        int id = __ibDatastore.nextValidId;
        System.out.println("starting reqContractDetails: " + id);
        __clientSocket.reqContractDetails(id, contract);
    }

Once I see contractDetailsEnd triggered, I trigger code to go through the list of all contracts and reqMktData (snapshot = true, so this is not streaming data):
public void onContractDetailsComplete() {
        //Received all contracts. Next step: Request market data for each contract.
        ArrayList<Contract> contracts = __ibDatastore.getContracts();
        contracts.forEach( contract -> {
            int id = __ibDatastore.nextValidId++;
            System.out.println("Starting: " + id);
            __clientSocket.reqMktData(id, contract, "", true, false, null);
        }
    }

From here, I listen for tickPrice and tickOptionComputation:
@Override
public void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, TickAttrib tickAttrib) {
    ...
    if (field == 1) {
        tick.bid = price;
        if (tick.ask != -1 && tick.delta != -1) {
            __ibDatastore.reqMktDataComplete(tickerId); //callback to cancel reqMktData
        }
    }
    else {
        tick.ask = price;
        if (tick.bid != -1 && tick.delta != -1) {
            __ibDatastore.reqMktDataComplete(tickerId); //callback to cancel reqMktData
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void tickOptionComputation(...) {
       ...
        tick.delta = delta;
        tick.currentPrice = undPrice;
        if (tick.bid != -1 && tick.ask != -1) {
            __ibDatastore.reqMktDataComplete(tickerId); //callback to cancel reqMktData
        }
    }

And the code to cancel the mktData is simply:
public void reqMktDataComplete(int tickerId) {
    __clientSocket.cancelMktData(tickerId);
}

